# how do I convert an xml file to an object literal in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps api to display a map on a site.

On this map i am creating markers.
I want to initialize the markers from an xml file.
the google.maps.Marker() constructor takes an object literal as a parameter.

this is an object literal that i can pass in to create a marker.

```
var options = {
    position: event.latLng,
    draggable: true,
    id: map.mobiles.length
}
```

this is an example of the xml file i am trying to initialize the marker with.

```
<marker>
    <position></position>
    <draggable>true</draggable>
    <id></id>
</marker>
```

a point in the right direction would be appreciated

Comment: Do you just want to [create Markers from XML](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-maps-api-3%5D+markers+from+XML)?

Comment: [Example that creates markers from XML from the Google Maps Javascript API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3) (the XML comes from a database, that part may or not be useful).

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved it.

Using http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/, i can convert xml to a json object, which looks like it will be a suitable approach since the format of the json object is very similar to an object literal